# How can I remove a symbol in a library(.lib) under ccs

Tags: c

There are two library which contains one same symbol, this leads to a redefinition when linking the lib. How can I remove a specific symbol in a lib?

The developing environment is CCS3.3, the duplicated symbol is _sature which is defined in rst6740.lib.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you want to modify distribution supplied libs rather than checking that you pass all the necessary compiler flags and define all the necessary macros?

Comment: This http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Managing_Symbols_with_the_Linker#--hide_and_--unhide might help.

Answer (score 0):

Good question !

In my opinion, you should rebuilt rst6740.lib.
You can find out the library code "rtssrc.zip" in folder that you setup the compiler.
Example : C:\ti\C6000_Code_Generation_Tools_7.3.7\lib.

That is code of library that will used to build the rts6740.lib,rts6400.lib...
Then you should remove the code of sature function and rebuilt the  rst6740.lib.

How to rebuild this lib you can search in Google.
Now i don't remember clearly step by step to rebuild it.